# jquery Optiscroll not working

Tags: jquery-plugins, scrollbar

I am using Optiscroll jquery plugin to customize default browser scrollbar. I want to change the body scrollbar.

```
$('body').optiscroll()
```

This is not working. All the things under wrapper hides.

I added a wrapper in body and it is also not working.

```
$('.wrapper').optiscroll()


<body>
<div class="wrapper optiscroll">
<!-- Code here-->
</div>
</body>
```

Any solution please?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The thing is `optiscroll` will set the height of your `scroll` element to 0. To make it appearing again, just change its height to something else.